# Adding a TEXT field to entity framework model for MySql

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to add a text field to my EDMX file which I have set to generate DDL for MySql. but the only option I have is to add a string with the maximum length set to Max. This is reporting a error when executing the SQL statements against the database, that the maxlength of 4000 is not supported.

I also tried it the other way around, updating the field in the database and than update the EDMX file based on the database, but that sets the field back to a string field with maximum length set to None.

Am I overlooking something? Have anyone used this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I have a kind of workaround to have my text field in the database mapped to the string property in the EDMX model. I generate the database script from the EDMX file and manually update the type for the TEXT columns from nvarchar(1000) to TEXT, execute it against the database and after that validate the mappings in the EDMX file.

Hopefully someone will come up with a better solution, because this is definitly not a cool workaround.

**Update**

This bug is fixed in Mysql Connector for .Net version 6.4.4

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the entity framework, however a TEXT field in mysql does not have a length as part of its definition. Only CHAR/VARCHAR does.

There is a maximum lenght of data that can be stored in TEXT, which is 64kb.

Comment: Actually that's not really my question.